# REST: How do I build a request path with a parameter as first token?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, wildfly, resteasy

I am new to RESTful services. I usually develop Java EE applications and SOAP services in a JBoss / Wildfly environment. I am currently trying to find my way into RESTful services to broaden my knowledge. Since I am feeling familiar with JBoss / Wildfly I decided to go with RESTEasy.

I decided to create a RESTful service for an example pet shop chain. As a chain the pet shop has multiple stores which are identfied by a shop id (e.g. shop1, shop2, etc.). I have created multiple REST services to segment services based on technical functionality (e.g. article services => article.war, order service => orde.war, etc.

I want to create human readable URLs, like:
GET:
http://mypetshop.example/rest/{shopId}/article/{articleId}

POST with JSON formatted order content:
http://mypetshop.example/rest/{shopId}/order/create

So far I have only managed to create URLs like:
GET:
http://mypetshop.example/rest/article/{shopId}/{articleId}

POST with JSON formatted order content:
http://mypetshop.example/rest/order/create/{shopId}

Is my wanted REST path possible or do I have to keep up with my current solution?

Best regards,
CB

Here is an example code for article services:

ArticleRestApplication.java:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath(ArticleRestApplication.ROOT_PATH)
public class OrderRestApplication extends Application {
    public static final String ROOT_PATH = "/article";
}
```

ArticleService.java

```
public interface ArticleService{
    Article getArticle(String shopId, Integer articleId);
}
```

ArticleServiceImpl.java:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
public class ArticleServiceImpl implements ArticleService {
    public ArticleServiceImpl() {
        super();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{shopId}/{articleId}")
    public Article getArtikel(
      @PathParam("shopId") String shopId,
      @PathParam("articleId") Integer articleId) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Shop ID: \"%s\"", shopId));
        System.out.println(String.format("Article ID: \"%s\"", articleId));
        return gson.toJson(new Article(articleId));
    }
}
```

Article.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@XmlRootElement(name = "article")
public class Article implements Serializable {
    private String shopId;
    private int articleId;
    private String name = "Super pet food";
    private BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("1.00");
    private int unitsInStock = 1000;

    public Article(String shopId, int articleId) {
        super();
        this.shopId = shopId;
        this.articleId = articleId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do
like below

**rest/orders/1/completed**

Here rest in rest servlet path , orders for class, then using `@Path("{orderId}/completed")`

```
 @Path("orders")
public class OrderService {

    @GET
    @Path("{orderId}/completed")
    public String getOrders(@PathParam("orderId") String orderId) {
        return "orderId: " + orderId;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("summary")
    public String getOrdersSummary() {
        return "orders summary";
    }
}
```

Live demo at http://jerseyexample-ravikant.rhcloud.com/rest/orders/1/completed

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I adopted your example to my needs and it works like a charm. Thank you.